# Facebook and Linkedin Share buttons

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have put up facebook and Linkedin share buttons on a page in my website. I have set the fb opengraph tags for that page. I have also set up the meta tags with description i want to share on FB and Linkedin, but when i share the content on facebook i get a wrong url and description shared. Please have a look and give me any ideas where i am wrong.
[This is the page](http://tinyurl.com/bfoteyl)

Comment: I get the correct URL when I shared the test page via Facebook. How did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my URL and OG tags in facebook debugger [here](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and it pointed out i had a type error and also a description tag was missing, which is essential. Fixing these, made everything perfect.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to test their page against *both* Facebook and LinkedIn...

- **[Facebook Page Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)**
- **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**